# pyparsing a field that may or may not contain values

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a dataset that resemebles the following:

`Capture MICR - Serial:                  Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4:          Split:`

The problem that I am having is I can't figure out how I could properly write a capture for the "Capture MICR - Serial Field". This field could either be blank or contain an alphanumeric of varying length (I have the same problem with the other fields that could either be populated or blank.

I have tried some variations of the following, but am still coming up short.

`pp.Literal("Capture  MICR - Serial:") + pp.White(" ", min=1, max=0) + (pp.Word(pp.printables) ^ pp.White(" ", min=1, max=0))("crd_micr_serial") + pp.FollowedBy(pp.Literal("Pos44:"))`

I think that part of the problem is that the `Or` matches a parse for the longest match, which in this case could be a long whitespace character, with a single alphanumeric, but I would still want to capture the single value.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Does the literal 'Pos44:` always appear?

Comment: Yes, each of the elements that are followed by a ":" always appear.

Comment: In the sample record there's 'Capture MICR - Serial', in the sample code there's 'Credit  MICR - Serial'. You want to be able to capture whatever appears in this position and perhaps a value for this field? For instance, the record might be something like 'Capture MICR - Serial: 5678qo34         Pos44: ...'?

Comment: Yep, exactly. There was a typo in the code above, which I just fixed. Essentially, I just want to capture everything that is after the colon, and before the next field name, in this case "Pos44:".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to parse text like "A: valueA B: valueB C: valueC" is to use pyparsing's SkipTo class:

```
a_expr = "A:" + SkipTo("B:")
b_expr = "B:" + SkipTo("C:")
c_expr = "C:" + SkipTo(LineEnd())
line_parser = a_expr + b_expr + c_expr
```

I'd like to enhance this just a bit more:

- add a parse action to strip off leading and trailing whitespace
- add a results name to make it easy to get the results after the line has been parsed

Here is how that simple parser looks:

```
NL = LineEnd()
a_expr = "A:" + SkipTo("B:").addParseAction(lambda t: [t[0].strip()])('A')
b_expr = "B:" + SkipTo("C:").addParseAction(lambda t: [t[0].strip()])('B')
c_expr = "C:" + SkipTo(NL).addParseAction(lambda t: [t[0].strip()])('C')
line_parser = a_expr + b_expr + c_expr

line_parser.runTests("""
    A: 100 B: Fred C:
    A:  B: a value with spaces C: 42
""")
```

Gives:

```
 A: 100 B: Fred C:
['A:', '100', 'B:', 'Fred', 'C:', '']
- A: '100'
- B: 'Fred'
- C: ''


A:  B: a value with spaces C: 42
['A:', '', 'B:', 'a value with spaces', 'C:', '42']
- A: ''
- B: 'a value with spaces'
- C: '42'
```

I try to avoid copy/paste code when I can, and would rather automate the "A is followed by B" and 
"C is followed by end-of-line" with a list describing the different prompt strings, and then walking that list to build each
sub expression:

```
import pyparsing as pp

def make_prompt_expr(s):
    '''Define the expression for prompts as 'ABC:' '''
    return pp.Combine(pp.Literal(s) + ':')

def make_field_value_expr(next_expr):
    '''Define the expression for the field value as SkipTo(what comes next)'''
    return pp.SkipTo(next_expr).addParseAction(lambda t: [t[0].strip()])

def make_name(s):
    '''Convert prompt string to identifier form for results names'''
    return ''.join(s.split()).replace('-','_')

# use split to easily define list of prompts in order - makes it easy to update later if new prompts are added
prompts = "Capture MICR - Serial/Pos44/Trrt/Acct/Tc/Opt4/Split".split('/')

# keep a list of all the prompt-value expressions
exprs = []

# get a list of this-prompt, next-prompt pairs
for this_, next_ in zip(prompts, prompts[1:]  + [None]):
    field_name = make_name(this_)
    if next_ is not None:
        next_expr = make_prompt_expr(next_)
    else:
        next_expr = pp.LineEnd()

    # define the prompt-value expression for the current prompt string and add to exprs
    this_expr = make_prompt_expr(this_) + make_field_value_expr(next_expr)(field_name)
    exprs.append(this_expr)

# define a line parser as the And of all of the generated exprs
line_parser = pp.And(exprs)

line_parser.runTests("""\
Capture MICR - Serial:                  Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4:          Split:
Capture MICR - Serial:  1729XYZ                Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4: XXL         Split: 50
""")
```

Gives:

```
Capture MICR - Serial:                  Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4:          Split:
['Capture MICR - Serial:', '', 'Pos44:', '', 'Trrt:', '32904', 'Acct:', '', 'Tc:', '2064', 'Opt4:', '', 'Split:', '']
- Acct: ''
- CaptureMICR_Serial: ''
- Opt4: ''
- Pos44: ''
- Split: ''
- Tc: '2064'
- Trrt: '32904'


Capture MICR - Serial:  1729XYZ                Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4: XXL         Split: 50
['Capture MICR - Serial:', '1729XYZ', 'Pos44:', '', 'Trrt:', '32904', 'Acct:', '', 'Tc:', '2064', 'Opt4:', 'XXL', 'Split:', '50']
- Acct: ''
- CaptureMICR_Serial: '1729XYZ'
- Opt4: 'XXL'
- Pos44: ''
- Split: '50'
- Tc: '2064'
- Trrt: '32904'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, took me a few days to get back to this. This actually totally changed the way I structured the parse, much better and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

I used the `Combine` merely so that both arms of the `Or` would produce similar results, ie, with 'Pos44:' at the end of the result string where it can be plucked off. I'm unhappy about resorting to a regex.

```
>>> import pyparsing as pp
>>> record_A = 'Capture MICR - Serial:                  Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4:          Split:'
>>> record_B = 'Capture MICR - Serial: 76ZXP67            Pos44:  Trrt: 32904  Acct:        Tc:   2064        Opt4:          Split:'
>>> parser_fragment = pp.Combine(pp.White()+pp.Literal('Pos44:'))
>>> parser = pp.Literal('Capture MICR - Serial:')+pp.Or([parser_fragment,pp.Regex('.*?(?:Pos44\:)')])
>>> parser.parseString(record_A)
(['Capture MICR - Serial:', '                  Pos44:'], {})
>>> parser.parseString(record_B)
(['Capture MICR - Serial:', '76ZXP67            Pos44:'], {})
```