# Pyparsing: Parsing nested plaintext data with a key=value

Tags: python, key-value, pyparsing

I'm new to python and I'm trying to parse some data using pyparsing that looks like this

```
string2 = """
object1 {
        key1 = value1
        key2 = value2
        #key3 = value3
        key4 = value4
        #key5 = value5
        key6 = value6
        subobject1 {
            key1 = value1
            key2 = value2
            key3 = value3
        }
}
"""
```

And I can get a key=value pair using this code

```
def parse_objects(source):
    LBRACE,EQ,RBRACE,HASH = map(Suppress, '{=}#')
    object_name = Word(printables)
    #disable = MatchFirst(map(Literal, '#'.split()))
    key = Word(printables)
    value = Word(printables)

    if LineStart() == HASH:
        key_and_value = Group(HASH + key('key') + EQ + value('value'))
    else:
        key_and_value = Group(key('key') + EQ + value('value'))

    collection = Forward()
    object_body = Group(LBRACE + ZeroOrMore(collection | key_and_value) + RBRACE)
    collection <<= Group(object_name + object_body)

    return collection.parseString(source)

collection = parse_objects(string2)
print(collection.dump())
```

But I also need to parsing data that does not contain values in objects, only keys. For example

```
object1 {
        key1 = value1
        key2
        #key3 = value3
        key4
        #key5 = value5
        key6 = value6
        subobject1 {
            key1 = value1
            key2 = value2
            key3 = value3
        }
}
```

I tried to make changes to the code and add the checking expression `if value is None`.
Something like this

```
if value is None:
    key_and_value = Group(key('key'))
else:
    if LineStart() == HASH:
        key_and_value = Group(HASH + key('key') + EQ + value('value'))
    else:
        key_and_value = Group(key('key') + EQ + value('value'))
```

but I get an error

```
Match W:(0123...) at loc 19(3,9)
Matched W:(0123...) -> ['key1']
Match W:(0123...) at loc 25(3,15)
Matched W:(0123...) -> ['value1']
Match W:(0123...) at loc 41(4,9)
Matched W:(0123...) -> ['key2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\my_projects\test_parser.py", line 86, in <module>
    collection = parse_objects(string2)
  File "c:\Python27\my_projects\test_parser.py", line 84, in parse_objects
    return collection.parseString(source)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1632, in parseString
    raise exc
ParseException: Expected "}" (at char 41), (line:4, col:9)
```

I think that pyparsing takes the key as the subobject and does not find `{`.
Can anyone give me any advices? Maybe I need to change my approach to  the grammar?
I appreciate any help.

**Edit 1**

@Jappy's solution works great for data that I wrote above, when subobject1 section at the bottom of the main section. After analyzing my data, I found that after the subobject1 section there may be more key=value pairs or only the keys, something like this:

```
string2 = """
object1 {
        key1 = value1
        key2
        #key3 = value3
        key4 = value4
        subobject1 {
            key1 = value1
            key2 = value2
            key3 = value3
        }        
        #key5 = value5
        key6 = v_a_l_u_e_6
        subobject2 {
            key1 = value1
        }
        key7 = value7
        key8
}
"""
```

Output will be following:

```
[['object1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'null'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'value4'], ['subobject1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', ['key1', 'value1']], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', 'null']]]
- objects: ['object1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'null'], ['#key3', 'value3'],
['key4', 'value4'], ['subobject1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', ['key1', 'value1']], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', 'null']]
  - key_val_lines: [['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', 'null']]
    [0]:
      ['key7', 'value7']
      - key: 'key7'
      - val: 'value7'
    [1]:
      ['key8', 'null']
      - key: 'key8'
      - val: 'null'
  - obj_name: 'object1'
  - objects: ['subobject2', ['key1', 'value1']]
    - key_val_lines: [['key1', 'value1']]
      [0]:
        ['key1', 'value1']
        - key: 'key1'
        - val: 'value1'
    - obj_name: 'subobject2'
```

I changed the code like this:

```
ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)
name_expr = Word(printables, excludeChars='{}')
key_val_expr = '=' + Word(printables)

key_val_line = Group(name_expr('key') + (lineEnd().setParseAction(lambda t: 'null') | key_val_expr)('val'))
#key_val_lines = OneOrMore(key_val_line)('key_val_lines')

obj = Forward()
objects = Group('{' + OneOrMore(key_val_line | obj) + '}')
obj << Group(name_expr('obj_name') + objects('objects'))
#obj << Group(name_expr('obj_name') + '{' + OneOrMore(key_val_lines | obj) + '}')('objects')

o = obj.parseString(string2)
print o.dump()
```

And the result is:

```
[['object1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'null'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4',
'value4'], ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', 'null']]]]
[0]:
  ['object1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'null'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'value4'], ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', 'null']]]
  - obj_name: 'object1'
  - objects: [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'null'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4',
'value4'], ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', 'null']]
    [0]:
      ['key1', 'value1']
      - key: 'key1'
      - val: 'value1'
    [1]:
      ['key2', 'null']
      - key: 'key2'
      - val: 'null'
    [2]:
      ['#key3', 'value3']
      - key: '#key3'
      - val: 'value3'
    [3]:
      ['key4', 'value4']
      - key: 'key4'
      - val: 'value4'
    [4]:
      ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]]
      - obj_name: 'subobject1'
      - objects: [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]
        [0]:
          ['key1', 'value1']
          - key: 'key1'
          - val: 'value1'
        [1]:
          ['key2', 'value2']
          - key: 'key2'
          - val: 'value2'
        [2]:
          ['key3', 'value3']
          - key: 'key3'
          - val: 'value3'
    [5]:
      ['#key5', 'value5']
      - key: '#key5'
      - val: 'value5'
    [6]:
      ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6']
      - key: 'key6'
      - val: 'v_a_l_u_e_6'
    [7]:
      ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]]
      - obj_name: 'subobject2'
      - objects: [['key1', 'value1']]
        [0]:
          ['key1', 'value1']
          - key: 'key1'
          - val: 'value1'
    [8]:
      ['key7', 'value7']
      - key: 'key7'
      - val: 'value7'
    [9]:
      ['key8', 'null']
      - key: 'key8'
      - val: 'null'
```

But I could not `setResultsName` to the Group instead `[0]` index:

```
obj << Group(name_expr('obj_name') + objects('objects'))('section')
```

returns wrong result.

Comment: What is the significance of the '#' character? Does it indicate a comment? Or a special kind of key?

Comment: '#' character means that the key is disabled in the configuration file.
Next, I want to check the list of keys and find active and disabled

Comment: @PaulMcG: Maybe I can use pyparsing's SkipTo class? Something like this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44890040/pyparsing-a-field-that-may-or-may-not-contain-values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897072/9993392)?
But I still can not understand..

Comment: Alternative library https://github.com/chimpler/pyhocon/blob/master/README.md

Comment: @cricket_007, thank you, it looks interesting. I'll look at this library

Answer (score 1):

This should help you out. See comments for details.

```
from pyparsing import *

test_string ='''
object1 {
        key1 = value1
        key2
        #key3 = value3
        key4
        #key5 = value5
        key6 = value6
        subobject1 {
            key1 = value1
            key2 = value2
            key3 = value3
        }
}'''

# interpret inline 'string' as Suppress('string'), 
# instead of LBRACE,EQ,RBRACE,HASH = map(Suppress, '{=}#')
ParserElement.inlineLiteralsUsing(Suppress)  

# be sure to exclude special characters when using printables
name_expr = Word(printables, excludeChars='{}')
key_val_expr = '=' + Word(printables)

# p1('name') is equivalent to p1.setResultsName('name')
# p1 | p2 is equivalent to MatchFirst(p1, p2)
# if lineEnd() matches first, there is no value. 
# then use a parse action to return the string 'NONE' as value instead
# else, match a regular key_value
# also, you have to use Group because key_val_line is a repeating element
key_val_line = Group(name_expr('key') + (lineEnd().setParseAction(lambda t: 'NONE') | key_val_expr)('val'))
key_val_lines = OneOrMore(key_val_line)('key_val_lines')

obj = Forward()
obj << Group(name_expr('obj_name') + '{' + OneOrMore(key_val_lines | obj) + '}')('objects')

parse_results = obj.parseString(test_string)
print(parse_results.dump())
```

This prints the following:

```
[['object1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'NONE'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'NONE'], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'value6'], ['subobject1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]]]
- objects: ['object1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'NONE'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'NONE'], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'value6'], ['subobject1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]]
  - key_val_lines: [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'NONE'], ['#key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'NONE'], ['#key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'value6']]
    [0]:
      ['key1', 'value1']
      - key: 'key1'
      - val: 'value1'
    [1]:
      ['key2', 'NONE']
      - key: 'key2'
      - val: 'NONE'
    [2]:
      ['#key3', 'value3']
      - key: '#key3'
      - val: 'value3'
    [3]:
      ['key4', 'NONE']
      - key: 'key4'
      - val: 'NONE'
    [4]:
      ['#key5', 'value5']
      - key: '#key5'
      - val: 'value5'
    [5]:
      ['key6', 'value6']
      - key: 'key6'
      - val: 'value6'
  - obj_name: 'object1'
  - objects: ['subobject1', ['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]
    - key_val_lines: [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]
      [0]:
        ['key1', 'value1']
        - key: 'key1'
        - val: 'value1'
      [1]:
        ['key2', 'value2']
        - key: 'key2'
        - val: 'value2'
      [2]:
        ['key3', 'value3']
        - key: 'key3'
        - val: 'value3'
    - obj_name: 'subobject1'
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeppi, your solution was very helpful for me. But I changed it a little, because again faced with errors when parsing my data. See **Edit 1** for details. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive parsers are not an easy first start with pyparsing, and your optional bits make things more complicated too. I think this code mostly does what you want - hopefully it will be more meaningful to you now that you have done some of your own wrestling with pyparsing thus far:

```
import pyparsing as pp

LBRACE, RBRACE, EQ = map(pp.Suppress, "{}=")
# convert parsed '#' to a bool that you can test on
disabled_marker = pp.Literal("#").addParseAction(lambda: True)
identifier = pp.pyparsing_common.identifier
key = identifier()

# try to parse a numeric value first, might be interesting
# pyparsing_common.number will auto-convert string to float or int at parse time,
# so you won't have to detect and do the conversion later
value = pp.pyparsing_common.number | pp.Word(pp.printables)

obj_item = pp.Forward()
obj_expr = pp.Group(identifier("name")
                    + pp.Group(LBRACE
                               + pp.ZeroOrMore(obj_item)
                               + RBRACE)("attributes"))

key_with_value = pp.Group(pp.Optional(disabled_marker)("disabled")
                          + key("key") + EQ + value("value"))
# use empty() to inject a None for the value
key_without_value = pp.Group(pp.Optional(disabled_marker)("disabled")
                             + key("key") 
                             + pp.empty().addParseAction(lambda: [None])("value"))

# now define an item that can be used in an object - this order is important!
obj_item <<= obj_expr | key_with_value | key_without_value
```

To parse your `string2` input:

```
zz = obj_expr.parseString(string2)
print(zz[0].dump())
```

Gives:

```
['object1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', None], [True, 'key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'value4'], ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]], [True, 'key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', None]]]
- attributes: [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', None], [True, 'key3', 'value3'], ['key4', 'value4'], ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]], [True, 'key5', 'value5'], ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6'], ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]], ['key7', 'value7'], ['key8', None]]
  [0]:
    ['key1', 'value1']
    - key: 'key1'
    - value: 'value1'
  [1]:
    ['key2', None]
    - key: 'key2'
    - value: None
  [2]:
    [True, 'key3', 'value3']
    - disabled: True
    - key: 'key3'
    - value: 'value3'
  [3]:
    ['key4', 'value4']
    - key: 'key4'
    - value: 'value4'
  [4]:
    ['subobject1', [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]]
    - attributes: [['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2'], ['key3', 'value3']]
      [0]:
        ['key1', 'value1']
        - key: 'key1'
        - value: 'value1'
      [1]:
        ['key2', 'value2']
        - key: 'key2'
        - value: 'value2'
      [2]:
        ['key3', 'value3']
        - key: 'key3'
        - value: 'value3'
    - name: 'subobject1'
  [5]:
    [True, 'key5', 'value5']
    - disabled: True
    - key: 'key5'
    - value: 'value5'
  [6]:
    ['key6', 'v_a_l_u_e_6']
    - key: 'key6'
    - value: 'v_a_l_u_e_6'
  [7]:
    ['subobject2', [['key1', 'value1']]]
    - attributes: [['key1', 'value1']]
      [0]:
        ['key1', 'value1']
        - key: 'key1'
        - value: 'value1'
    - name: 'subobject2'
  [8]:
    ['key7', 'value7']
    - key: 'key7'
    - value: 'value7'
  [9]:
    ['key8', None]
    - key: 'key8'
    - value: None
- name: 'object1'
```

EDIT: I removed the Dict constructs, as they actually make the output more difficult to process.

Comment: You are right, parsing the custom data structure was not so simple. I saw many examples and did not find any solutions for me.
Your trick with `disabled_marker` is very cool and separation on the `key_with_value` and `key_without_value` looks reasonably.
Your tips helped to understand the working of pyparsing.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeppi's answer has some excellent suggestions. I would add:

- `Word(printables)` is always a risky construct, since it will match as much non-whitespace as there is. For instance, if a line contained "color=red" with no spaces, then it would be interpreted as a key "color=red" with no value. You would be better to define key with something like `Word(alphanums)` or `Word(alphas, alphanums+"_")`. To allow for the possible leading '#', use `Word(alphas+'#', alphanums+"_")`.
- Your idea about conditionalizing the presence of '#' with `if LineStart() == HASH` is interesting, but not how pyparsing works. At this point in the code, you are still building the parser itself, which happens separate from any input text. The actual determination of whether a particular line starts with '#' happens during parsing, which is done later when your code calls `collection.parseString`. That is, you build up all the parser bits, and then point them at the source text. Any "if character X is present" logic needs to be represented using some alternation or optional construct in the parser itself, not with Python if-then code.
- Consider using pyparsing's Optional class for elements that may or may not be present. This applies to the possible `key-value` without a value, and could also be another way to handle the possible leading '#' character in key names.

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I will definitely use `Word (alphas, alphanums)` + special characters.
Explanation of `#` and logic of pyparsing is very useful fo me.
I used @Jappy's solution and changed my code, you can also see my **Edit 1** and say something about this?